# Member-wise assignment in scala?

Tags: scala

Does scala support memberwise assignment?

Given:

```
case class C(var x:Int, var y:Int)
val c = C(1,2)
val d = C(3,4)
```

is there an operator to assign each member of d to c.

In C/C++ you would have:

```
struct C{ int x, int y)
C c = {1,2}
C d = {3,4}

c = d
```

**edit1**

One of the great benefits of member-wise assignment is that its automatic, in

Both

```
c() = d
```

and

```
c.copyFrom( d )
```

both suffer from a maintenance problem - if new members are added members to C its easy to overlook adding the member to the user-created function. What's really desired is automated way to copy these values.

**edit2**

Another use case for this behavior:

```
val props:ThirdPartyType = ThirdPartyLibrary.getProperties()
val myprops:ThirdPartyType = MyLibrary.loadPropertiesFromFile()
props @= myprops  // magic member-wise assignment
```

Here we may find:

- We're stuck with ThirdPartyLibrary and ThirdPartyType (can't change it)
- The library doesn't provide the ability to reassign the property object.
- The library does provide the ability to assign the property's values. It behaves as a JavaBean POJO with public members.

I can do:

```
props.a = myprops.a
props.b = myprops.b
...
```

but this pattern break when we update to V2 of the ThirdParty library. ThirdPartyType has gained new members that we didn't not copy.

Can't this be solved through reflection?

Comment: What is class `D`? Did you typo `C` as `D` in your first code snippet?

Comment: Yes, was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The enhancement is easy:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class C(var x:Int, var y:Int)
val c = C(1,2)
val d = C(3,4)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class C
c: C = C(1,2)
d: C = C(3,4)

scala> implicit class CUpdater(val c: C) { def update(d: C) = { c.x=d.x ; c.y=d.y } }
defined class CUpdater

scala> c() = d

scala> c
res1: C = C(3,4)
```

Usual caveats around mutability apply. And you didn't hear it from me.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this has a terrible maintenance burden. If a member is added to C, you will certainly forget to update CUpdater. I've updated my original post with extra use cases.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you a separate object with all case class constructor arguments copied over, although it will not change the original object that `d` pointed to:

```
d = c.copy()
```

If you really want to modify the original object that `d` points to (perhaps because you have a reference to it somewhere else - think of pointers to structs in the C programming language), then I think you would have to do something fancy with metaprogramming (i.e. reflection or macros) to get a general solution for this.

But I recommend programming with immutable `val`s, almost always! If you can live with that, `copy` is fine.

Comment: Thank you -- I understand the pointers, references, immutability, etc..  very precisely. I'm mainly interested in whether the language has this specific feature. I'd like to replace values in an existing object, to which many other objects already have a reference.

Comment: That way madness lies!

Comment: @Randall. Maybe -- immutability is a religious position. Although its frequently useful, its also frequently neither necessary nor beneficial. For example, where immutable collections leads us: copying a 100Mb database structure just to insert an item in the middle has limited benefits where my program is single threaded. 

There's madness in excessive application of design patterns. I'm looking at you Eclipse -- hovering around 12gb of resident memory! And you Spring, with your endless onion of abstractions. Its elephants all the way down....

Comment: I eschew dogma, but for a large majority of cases, immutable structures are the right choice. Experience (long experience!) has taught and continues to teach me that immutability is the proper default with mutability requiring specific justification based on *empirically* determined properties such as running time and space requirements. When mutable constructs are employed, extreme vigilance is required to maintain correctness, most especially in the face of concurrent and parallel programming.

Comment: Broadly I agree, immutability if usually good. Anyhow, I've updated the example which makes the immutability discussion moot.